# Grading of exterior algebra given by generators

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I'm having troubles understanding exterior algebra graded structure.

I need to write the polynomial (a sort of Poincare polynomial) given by
$P(t)=\sum_{p=0}^{N} (\dim \Lambda^p )\ t^p,$
where $\Lambda$ is an exterior algebra $\Lambda=\Lambda(x_1,...,x_l)$ with generators $x_i$ of degree $d_i,$ and $N=\sum_{i=1}^l d_i.$

Is it correct to say that

$$\Lambda^p \text{ has basis given by } \left\{ x_{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge x_{i_k} \ \vert \ 1 \leq i_1 < ... <i_k \leq l, \  \sum_{m=1}^k d_{i_m}=p \right\}$$

If that's the case, the polynomial $P(t)$ would have the form
$$P(t)=\prod_{i=1}^l (1 + t^{d_i})$$
Am I correct?

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: What is a "generator of degree $d_i$"?

Comment: If the "generators" are basis vectors of the (graded) vector space over which you're forming the graded exterior algebra, and $\Lambda^p$ is the subspace of homogeneous elements of degree $p$, then this looks correct.